# What is the relationship between classification_report and precision_score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I want to use `classification_report`, `accuracy_score`, `precision_score`,
`recall_score` and
`f1_score` evaluation index to evaluate my machine learning model.

The `classification_report` has normal output but my `precision_score` reports an error.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score  
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score   
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score      
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score         

print(accuracy_score(y_test,predicted))
print(precision_score(y_test,predicted))
print(recall_score(y_test,predicted))
print(f1_score(y_test,predicted))
```

```
ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label. It should be one of ['ham', 'spam']
```

Classification report：

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
model_report_test_correct=classification_report(y_test,predicted)
print(model_report_test_correct)

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

     ham       0.96      1.00      0.98      1208
    spam       1.00      0.74      0.85       185

accuracy                           0.96      1393
macro avg      0.98      0.87      0.91      1393
weighted avg   0.97      0.96      0.96      1393
```

Comment: classification_report has option to show labels, while other sklearn.metrics  do not show labels. It needs to receive 1 and 0 as a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty explanatory: you need to specify `pos_label` to be either "ham" or "spam" (and the precision should be 1.00 or 0.96 respectively).

(Accuracy doesn't error because its definition doesn't care about which is the "positive" class, but recall and f1 will also need this specified.)